# Как получить больше данных на onion-сайте в TOR?

Tags: php, tor, onion

Создал onion-сайт, но переменная `$_SERVER` не отображает ничего полезного. Мне кажется, можно как-то получить информацию о цепочке, её IP и т.д., но как это сделать? Может в TOR всё иначе?

```
Array
(
    [HTTP_HOST] => kabuxgvkn2z4dotz.onion
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at kabuxgvkn2z4dotz.onion Port 80


    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
    [SERVER_NAME] => kabuxgvkn2z4dotz.onion
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 36096
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => debug=1
    [REQUEST_URI] => /?debug=1
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1606265637.799
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1606265637
)
```

Comment: `Создал onion-site` - это как? Просто домен такой прописал?

Comment: @vp_arth он там при первом запуске тор генерирует ключи на основе RSA  Домен получается, соответсвенно, либо рандомный либо из заранее сгенерированного ключа.

Comment: @DiD, меня смутил `SERVER_ADDR => 127.0.0.1`, т.е. это обычный локальный сайт/домен. В Тор тут должен был быть последний элемент цепочки..

Comment: А если бы сервер знал всю цепочку(как предполагается в вопросе), в Тор не было бы никакого смысла ..

Comment: @vp_arth Клиент знает только три последних узла, по которому подключается пользователь. Сервер Web подходит любой локальный. Я бы не стал использовать PHP (но о вкусах не спорят, кто-то и на винде все это поднимает). В конфигах тора настраиваются маппинги портов. Можно поднять любой сервис (не обязательно web-сервер: чаты, почта, криптовалюты, ботнеты). Можно поднять много серверов на одном домене и на разных доменах (по каждому домену должен быть запущен отдельный процесс тора).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такую информацию можно получить из логов тора. По сигналу SIGUSR1 процессу Тора, Тор выдает в лог информацию о текущем состоянии. Либо активировать режим Debug путем посылания процессу тора сигнала SIGUSR2. Подробнее в [документации Тора](https://tor.void.gr/docs/tor-manual.html.en).

Либо подключаться к ControlPort используя протокол описанный в [спецификациях тора](https://spec.torproject.org/). Программы, которые подключаются к нему для приимера можно взять со странички [Support Programs](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/SupportPrograms).